# How do I highlight a filter button when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a filter button. When clicking it the filter button should be highlighted via shadow. Can please anybody give some suggetions?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: What you tried we need to see first so code pls...

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```css
.myfilter:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #FFFF00; /* use any color you like*/
}
```

```html
<input class="myfilter" type="text" placeholder="click me"  value="">
<input class="myfilter" type="button"   value="Click me too">
```

I used CSS `focus` to highlight the input when it is clicked

Comment: use button tag instead of input as he said button :)

Comment: i was going to but i don't want to steal your points so i din..:)

Comment: woww from 1 year 2 month..first time my comments got upvote..really thanx..:)

Comment: ha ha ha you deserve it...

Comment: thanx as m famous in SO to get down votes.yesterday my ans got delete as 4 vote down  even it was correct and marked as ans still so..:)